# How to supply arguments using CMake and CTest?

Tags: testing, build-process, automated-tests, cmake, ctest

In the test that I want to run using CTest I should be adding the test that I want to run, with the following command:

```
add_test(TestName ExeName)
```

The problem is what if I want to supply an argument to the TestName, where do I put it?
How do I run ctest individually without cmake in unix command line in this context?

Answer (score 3):

Insert the following command in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
ENABLE_TESTING()
```

Next add the test(s):

```
add_test(testname Executable args)
```

To determine what tests are available, you can always run:

```
ctest -N
```

The second way of specifying tests is using explicit test number option -I:

```
ctest -I 3
```

will run the test number 3.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are passed after the executable name just like in the command line.

```
enable_testing()

add_test(FirstTest app.exe 100)
add_test(SecondTest app.exe 200)
add_test(ThirdTest app.exe 300)
```

Tests can be run based on the "index" of the test with the `-I` option.

```
ctest -I 2,3
```

Specific tests can be run based on the test name too with the `-R` option.

```
ctest -R "Second"
```